# Spring Boot App deployed to Weblogic 11g Won't Start

Tags: java, spring, weblogic, spring-boot

I'm having some issues deploying a Spring Boot application to a Weblogic 10.3.3 Server.  I'm desperately crossing my fingers in hopes that someone has seen this issue before.  I use Weblogic's admin console to perform the deployment (and that seems to go well), but I get an error from Weblogic when I attempt to start the application:

```
Caused By: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid source 'com.example.Application'
    at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:223)
    at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:144)
    at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.load(SpringApplication.java:620)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:139)
    at org.springframework.boot.legacy.context.web.SpringBootContextLoaderListener.initWebApplicationContext(SpringBootContextLoaderListener.java:61)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:481)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:181)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1863)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3126)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1512)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:486)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:41)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:41)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:1267)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:41)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:409)
    at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:43)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.doCommit(StartOperation.java:143)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:528)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
```

The app is deployed as a WAR file using spring-boot-legacy and a web.xml.  It runs fine on Tomcat 6/7/8.  Here are my relevant config files:

### web.xml

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>com.example.Application</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.boot.legacy.context.web.SpringBootContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>helloWorld</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextAttribute</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>helloWorld</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

### weblogic.xml

```
<wls:weblogic-web-app 
xmlns:wls="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app 
    http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.0/weblogic-web-app.xsd">

<wls:context-root>helloWorld</wls:context-root>

<wls:container-descriptor>
    <wls:prefer-application-packages>
        <wls:package-name>org.slf4j.*</wls:package-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-packages>
</wls:container-descriptor>
```

Tracing through the stack trace, it appears that Spring Boot's BeanDefinitionLoader class attempts to load the source classes (in my case, just `com.example.Application`) but fails because it doesn't see it as a class, resource, or package.  Looking at the BeanDefinitionLoader class here: [BeanDefinitionLoader.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/BeanDefinitionLoader.java%20BeanDefiit) (line 187), it appears that my Application class should get loaded as a Class.  Like I mentioned, it does work great in Tomcat, just not in Weblogic.

Is there something Weblogic-specific that I'm missing?  Could it be a file encoding issue?  Am I missing something from my web.xml?

Thanks for your time!

### Update #1

After exhausting Google and StackOverflow for things to try, I added the `spring.main.sources: com.example.Application` to my application.yml.  It had no effect.

My current hunch right now is that the **contextAttribute** parameter in my web.xml might have something to do with my issue.  Just unsure what else I can change it to.  Thoughts?

Comment: Downvoting for cutesy ironic pseudohipster title.

Comment: @CPerkins lol fair enough...I'll change the title.  Figures though.  My first question to stackoverflow and I come across as too cutesy.  Not cool.

Comment: It seems like some sort of classpath issue still, what does your war structure look like? Do you need to add spring to your `prefer-application-packages` so it doesn't use the version that comes with weblogic? Upvoted because I never saw the title

Comment: Sorry to have been snarky.  I'm not getting enough sleep lately.  It's a good question.  Downvote reversed.

Comment: @CPerkins - No worries.  It was good advice.

Comment: @DisplayNameismissing My WAR structure is as follows:

META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
WEB-INF/
    classes/
        application.yml
        com/example/ (classes)
    lib/ (dependencies)
    web.xml
    weblogic.xml

It's fairly simple as this is mostly a test app to see if I can get it running on Weblogic (customer requirement).  I can't quite pinpoint if it's a classpath issue as it runs fine in Tomcat.  Does Weblogic load classes from a WAR differently than Tomcat?

Comment: @DisplayNameismissing My original post title had "The Struggle is REAL" appended to it.  Been working this issue for several days and it just seemed appropriate.

Comment: Did you implement `WebApplicationInitializer` in your Application class? Were you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Check that your building your war with the same version of Java as the Weblogic server is running. Eg if it's 1.6 set JAVA_HOME to your 1.6 JDK before running gradle build.

Answer (score 0):

Does boot need higher version of servlet version than Weblogic 10.3.3 Server supports? Does this version bit old??

Comment: It does https://github.com/dsyer/spring-boot-legacy but like the original poster I'm dealing with the same Invalid Source even with the legacy bits. Ever more strange is I have one project that works just great, while the other fails. So I'm in the process of trying to figure out the difference. Once is a WebMVC and one is strictly web service. I was hoping that's not the issue, but I'm about to make the other one a WebMVC just to see. I'll report back with my findings.